# Creating shapefile containing terrain, buildi ng and road layers from OS UK maps using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I'm new to GIS.

I would like to create a shapefile map using QGIS containing contours, buildings and road information layers which can be exported to other software to build a 3D model.

I have downloaded the OS Terrain 50 map (all of UK) and OS VectorMap District (National Grid Ref Square: SO) from the Ordinance Survey UK site. I am only interested in a specific area of 1 square km within the Grid Ref 50 Map.

Is it possible to extract the Contour information from the Terrain 50 Map and the road and building information from the District Map and overlay them in QGIS and then export as shapefile?

Comment: first part: shapefiles only accept one kind of geometry, point, line or polygon; you want to create a plain map (not a "shapefile map"), putting several layers together on the map (but not in a file); for extracting areas you use the "clip" function under vector tab

Comment: So it is possible. Will the roads and buildings be automatically adjusted to the correct height when overlayed on the contour map?

Comment: Usually, shapefiles don't contain height values. Most tools will export only 2D values. You will need to adjust elevation yourself on the 3D modelling tool once you have 3D models. Many 3D tools have options to adjust objects to floor, or maybe you can write your own scripts.